# ShadowApplication: registered receivers contain uninitialized object under test

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, robolectric

First, I get a spied instance of my class under test:

```
TestedClass testedClass = spy(new TestedClass(Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class).create().get());
```

Then, some changes happen to the tested class:
testedClass.someString = "whatever"

Then, I simulate sending an intent to a broadcast receiver registered in the tested class:

```
    ShadowApplication shadowApplication = Robolectric.getShadowApplication();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    List<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceivers = shadowApplication.getReceiversForIntent(intent);
    broadcastReceivers.get(0).onReceive(Robolectric.application, intent);
```

The BroadcastReceiver is found in the list, so I can call onReceive and onReceive event is fired:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Log.i(tag, someString);
}
```

However, the TestedClass object that appears is an uninitialized version, this is:   `someString == ""`
It's not the same object that was being spied.
Maybe, it's the normal behaviour, but I would like to get the same instance I created for the test, not a mocked one created parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you instance the BroadcastReceiver.

If you instance the BroadcastReceiver with a default value, the simulated calls to the BroadcastReceiver won't be executed

```
//Class member myBroadcastReceiver
public BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
```

However, if you instance the BroadcastReceiver later, it works properly:

```
public myBroadcastReceiver;
public initializeBroadcastReceiver() {
    myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
}
```

These are the facts, nonetheless, I still don't know if the first case is expected behaviour or it is a flaw of Robolectric.